# Way to retain offline maps during had reset?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, maps, hard-reset

I have some offline maps on my SD card. I am about to hard reset my phone. I know apps on SD card will not work after that. But is there a way to reuse my offline maps that are stored on my SD card?

As far as I see Mapdata is a visible folder with files unlike app data. So I think the Maps app will automatically make use of it. Can anybody confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hard-reset, it'll ask you if you want to wipe the SD card too (assuming you didn't remove the card first). Don't wipe the card.

After hard-reset, the OS will default to storing maps on internal storage. Go to `Settings` -> `System` -> Offline maps` and tell the phone to store offline maps on the SD card, then exit Settings. You may also need to restart the phone, but it should find the existing map data automatically.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It detected the offline maps as soon as I changed the storage location. No restart was needed.